# I have 2 entries, I want to duplicate them and send them as an array, but only 1 data is sent, the data I duplicate does not go

Tags: javascript, laravel

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="maddeContainer">
    <!-- İlk Madde Başlığı ve Açıklaması -->
    <div class="form-row mt-1">
        <div class="form-group col-4 m-0">
            <label for="email" class="col-form-label s-12"><i class="icon-envelope-o mr-2"></i>Madde Başlığı</label>
            <input name="madde_t[]" placeholder="Madde Başlığı" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4 m-0">
            <label for="roll1" class="col-form-label s-12">Madde Açıklaması</label>
            <textarea name="madde_d[]" placeholder="Madde Açıklaması" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" type="text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2 mt-4 pt-2">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="deleteMadde()"><i class="icon icon-delete"></i>Satır Sil</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2 mt-4 pt-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addNewMadde()"><i class="icon icon-plus-circle"></i>Yeni Ekle</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    let maddeCounter = 1;

    function addNewMadde() {
        maddeCounter++;

        // Yeni Madde Container oluştur
        var newMaddeContainer = document.createElement('div');
        newMaddeContainer.className = 'form-row mt-1';

        // Yeni Madde Başlığı
        var newMaddeTitle = document.createElement('div');
        newMaddeTitle.className = 'form-group col-4 m-0';
        newMaddeTitle.innerHTML = '<label for="email" class="col-form-label s-12"><i class="icon-envelope-o mr-2"></i>Madde Başlığı</label>' +
            '<input name="madde_t[]" placeholder="Madde Başlığı" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" type="text">';

        // Yeni Madde Açıklaması
        var newMaddeDescription = document.createElement('div');
        newMaddeDescription.className = 'form-group col-4 m-0';
        newMaddeDescription.innerHTML = '<label for="roll1" class="col-form-label s-12">Madde Açıklaması</label>' +
            '<textarea name="madde_d[]" placeholder="Madde Açıklaması" class="form-control r-0 light s-12" type="text"></textarea>';

        // Yeni Ekle Butonu
        var newButtonDelete = document.createElement('div');
        newButtonDelete.className = 'form-group col-2 mt-4 pt-2';
        newButtonDelete.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button" onclick="deleteMadde()"><i class="icon icon-delete"></i>Satır Sil</button>';

        var newButton = document.createElement('div');
        newButton.className = 'form-group col-2 mt-4 pt-2';
        newButton.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addNewMadde()"><i class="icon icon-plus-circle"></i>Yeni Ekle</button>';

        // Yeni eklenen alanları, sayfaya ekleyin
        newMaddeContainer.appendChild(newMaddeTitle);
        newMaddeContainer.appendChild(newMaddeDescription);
        newMaddeContainer.appendChild(newButtonDelete);
        newMaddeContainer.appendChild(newButton);

      document.getElementById("maddeContainer").appendChild(newMaddeContainer);
    }
</script>
```

I duplicated and filled the inputs 3 times, but the data comes like this:

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbe5W.png)

When I print the data I entered into the inputs with the dd command, it gives the following output. The first value in the inputs comes, but the other values ​​do not. I did the same codes in another project, but it works with the same codes.

```
"madde_t" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "dsadsa"
  ]
  "madde_d" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "dasdsa"
  ]
```

my project is a laravel project.

Comment: I am already sending the data as array. name="madde_d[]"

Comment: Can you share your entire blade file? I've tried to replicate this, but I get all values when I dd the request, not just the first, as you describe. Please also share your controller method, so we can rule out any issues there.

Comment: where can i share my blade file. my file so long

Comment: At least share the relevant parts. I don't see the form or the submit button.

Comment: my form is around 1500 lines.

Comment: Scrap the parts that are not relevant for this issue. Include these inputs, the wrapped form, and the submit button. As mentioned, I tried to replicate it, but was unable to, so I suspect there is something off in the form.

Comment: [my codes](https://vizyon.mayazilim.com/codes) here is my all codes